# SLB gaskets: water tight?

Tags: conduit, fitting, seal

I bought 2 cast aluminium SLBs (1-1/4") for conduit from the same big box store the other day. They had 2 different gaskets in the removable cover however. One was the common black rubber/neoprene gasket. The other was a red plastic/cardboard/cardstock type material. It is thinner than the black gasket and it is rigid, as in it does not feel like the lid flexes/compresses it as it presses it between the coverer and SLB body. I went back to the store to see if they had another with the black gasket, but the only one in stock was another with the red gasket. Does anyone have any experience with the red gaskets and know if they are fine for outdoor use? The listing on the website says the SLBs are, but I can't find any information mentioning the red gaskets, just the black gasket.

Comment: I know what an LB is but what is a SLB? Red gaskets are usually silicone but again maybe defining what an SLB is would help.

Comment: @EdBeal -- probably short for "service (entrance) LB"

Comment: Can you get us make/model info on said SLBs?